# updated 22.0.0 to 23.0.1 now getting adb not responding error in i tried all solution given below android studio 1.2.1.1 in ubuntu

Tags: android, shell, ubuntu

last day used it was fine, but after running adb shell today started android studio getting this error please help me quick.thanks

ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'
Errors from ADB:

> adb: /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")"
>   unexpected adb: 'adb version' failed!
>   /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")"
>   unexpected adb: Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':

**Standard Output was:**

Error Output was:

> /home/krishna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following instruction from [Google](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools):**

> If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine,
>   you need to install additional packages first. For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy
>   Salamander) and above, install the libncurses5:i386, libstdc++6:i386,
>   and zlib1g:i386 packages using apt-get:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

For earlier versions of ***Ubuntu***, install the `ia32-libs` package using apt-get:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: i have tried these 3 commands and then restarted system getting same error please help..

Comment: Check the solutions in this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143774/android-sdk-having-trouble-with-adb hope that helps

Comment: tried this link also but not worked for me please if there is detail solution for that please give to me step by step .. i think there is a little mistake in steps .trying about last 4 hour #ubuntu 14.04